ToC generation when building pdf using QuestPdf library
can anyone please kindly point me in the direction of an example of what would be most optimal method to implement simple Table of Contents when using QuestPdf library to generate PDF. i have spent some time scouting documentation as well as trying to search sample source code and on-line community but somehow blank out and unable to stumble against anything comprehensive. surely they would have this documented as this is naturally a core piece of pdf document, so it must be my dumb research skills right? thank you.

HMM ToC in PDF means 2 things one is the sidebar of "outline" named destination links (often called bookmarks) the other is a true ToC in page and an example is given at https://github.com/QuestPDF/QuestPDF/blob/main/Source/QuestPDF.ReportSample/Layouts/TableOfContentsTemplate.cs

Cheers mate. this is what i was looking for. much appreciated.

i was missing text.BeginPageNumberOfSection(locationName); and text.EndPageNumberOfSection(locationName); was not able to figure out how to grab a given section effective start and end pages. never found any documentation point where they are described.

after having been kindly guided to the correct code section - here is the snippet that contains all relevant code required to construct ToC. i used Table construct to structure ToC entries but its not imperative - you can decide yourself how to structure ToC entries, they might as well be placed as text lines.
this functionality is described in the Github repo as part of QuestPDF.ReportSample project which was confusing to me as i was intuitively expecting this functionality to be described as part of QuestPDF.Examples project but there is no mention of this in that project.
Anyway, here are key concepts:

when you build your PDF - its effectively a tree like structure where elements are containers. in each container you define child and what content it contains. here is my sample root method:
     public void Compose(IDocumentContainer container)
     {
         container.Page(page =>
         {
             page.Header().Element(Header);
             page.Content().Element(Content);
             page.Footer().Element(Footer);
         });
     }



and then the method to build Content which may span multiple pages and at times get complicated:
void Content(IContainer container)
{
    container.Column(column =>
    {
        column.Item().Element(FrontPageContent);
        column.Item().PageBreak();

        column.Item().Element(TableOfContents);
        column.Item().PageBreak();

        column.Item().Section("Overview").Element(ConstructOverviewSection);
        column.Item().PageBreak();

        column.Item().Section("Summary").Element(ConstructSummarySection);
        column.Item().PageBreak();

        column.Item().Section("Detailed Breakdown").Element(ConstructBreakDownSection);
        column.Item().PageBreak();    
    });
}

delegates passed to .Element() methods accept IContainer container which they can operate to construct content. the key aspect here is - the preceding .Section() method accepting section title basically wraps all content you will construct in the following .Element() method into the section boundary and treat it as part of defined section.
Later you should be able to grab start and end page numbers for each section you define and use it for ToC construction. here is a simple example of ToC entries represented as text lines. here is a basic example (disclaimer - all of this is basic prototyping which can be refactored to be optimized in real life):
    void ConstructTableOfContents(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Table(table =>
        {
            table.ColumnsDefinition(columns =>
            {
                columns.RelativeColumn(); // section title                 
                columns.ConstantColumn(80); // section pages
            });

            table.Cell().Row(1).Column(1).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Column(column =>
                {
                    column.Item().SectionLink("Overview").Text("Overview");
                });
            });

            table.Cell().Row(1).Column(2).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Text(text =>
                {
                    text.BeginPageNumberOfSection("Overview").FontSize(8).SemiBold();
                });
            });

            table.Cell().Row(2).Column(1).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Column(column =>
                {
                    column.Item().SectionLink("Summary").Text("Summary");
                });
            });

            table.Cell().Row(2).Column(2).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Text(text =>
                {
                    text.BeginPageNumberOfSection("Summary");
                });
            });

            table.Cell().Row(3).Column(1).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Column(column =>
                {
                    column.Item().SectionLink("Detailed Breakdown").Text("Detailed Breakdown");
                });
            });

            table.Cell().Row(3).Column(2).Element(StyleTableCell).Element(child =>
            {
                child.Text(text =>
                {
                    text.BeginPageNumberOfSection("Detailed Breakdown");
                });
            });
        });
    }

the following creates a clickable link with specified text which when clicked should take you to the section start:
column.Item().SectionLink("Detailed Breakdown").Text("Detailed Breakdown");

and the following will produce a text reflecting page number of a section start page:
text.BeginPageNumberOfSection("Detailed Breakdown");

